# How can I insert CSV file data as float in numpy matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, matrix

If I have a spreadsheet in CSV file with M rows and N columns, all float values, and if I want to insert them as float values into a matrix

(similar to how you could do double nested for loops for double data[M][N] in C++)

so that I can perform various mathematical operations on it, such as eigendecomposition or SVD...etc then how could I do it on python?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at numpy's `genfromtxt()` method.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt

data = genfromtxt(<file>, delimiter=<,>, dtype="float")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in `numpy` called `np.loadtxt` you can use that for your requirement.

```
import numpy as np
csv_data = np.loadtxt('yourcsvfile', usecols=A ,skiprows=B ,dtype='float')
```

In A position, Give the columns in the csv file you want.
For an example you want only 5th and 6th colomns of your csv, So

```
usecols=(5,6)
```

And you can skip rows is the csv files. Use B parameter to skip rows.
Example, `skiprows=1` will skip the first row and read the rest of csv file.